# SWIFT: difference between init and super.init

Tags: xcode, swift

I am reading The Swift Programming Language book by .

The book says that an Init is an initializer to set up the class when an instance is created. (What I understand is: By creating an instance the code block in init() will be executed).

However the book shows super.init but doesn't tell anything about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official documentation does cover the aspect of initializing a superclass:

> The init() initializer for Bicycle starts by calling super.init(), which calls the default initializer for the Bicycle class’s superclass, Vehicle. This ensures that the numberOfWheels inherited property is initialized by Vehicle before Bicycle has the opportunity to modify the property. After calling super.init(), the original value of numberOfWheels is replaced with a new value of 2.

Corresponding example code:

Superclass:

```
class Vehicle {
    var numberOfWheels = 0
    var description: String {
        return "\(numberOfWheels) wheel(s)"
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
class Bicycle: Vehicle {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        numberOfWheels = 2
    }
}
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID216)

Comment: Thanks I do understand it now :D. What I find strange is why do you need to change numberofWheels in bicycle if you are not using it in subclass. I could just create another property in bicycle or is it that when you initialize it you are using the same memory?

Comment: That's the whole point of inheritance. Every `Vehicle` has wheels, so the superclass can have the property `numberOfWheels`. If for instance you would create a `Tricycle : Vehicle`, you could set `numberOfWheels` to 3.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say you have an object

```
class myObject : NSObject {

    var a : Int
    var b : Int

    init() {
        a = 1
        b = 2
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Because `myObject` inherits from NSObject it must call super.init() to initialize all the properties on the object it inherits from. while your init initializes all the properties specific to your custom object.

Comment: why does super.init() is forced to be called after initializing a and b and why can't they be initialized after the super.init() call?

Comment: you definitely could. I was merely demonstrating that you can also initialize properties UNIQUE to your subclass are not dependent on calling `super.init()`. But if you tried to initialize a property in `superclass`, it would fail if you haven't called `super.init()`. Most times i we always call `super.init()` or you can go 1. properties unique to your class. 2.` super.init()` 3. properties you want to override in base class for easy reading of what properties are unique and which aren't. It's all preference but there is more than one way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

`super` is just reference to superclass and that superclass have `init` method, so by calling `super.init()` you call `init` method of superclass without parameters. If `init` method of superclass have parameters

```
class Animal {
    init(name: String) {

    }
}
```

you must pass parameters to this method

```
class Cat: Animal {
    init() {
        super.init(name: "Cat")
    }
}

class PersianCat: Cat {
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: In the subclass Cat you say: Super.init(name: "cat"). What can happen to the argument you passed? What can we do with "cat"  Can this go back to the superclass?

Comment: This is just a method. So we don't know and shouldn't care what will happen to "cat". But we must pass some value to be able to derive from `Animal`. Superclass may have some dependencies which we satisfy by passing parameters to `init`. Then superclass uses them but we may don't know how.